# Email Response Style is overriding my styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am developing an Email Web app using html5, css3, javascript, jquery

I am facing a problem in my Email Content rendering.

Some of the Email Contents (Technically, Response) has its own style, say for eg something like this

a
    {
        color:green;
    }

Hence all my anchor tags (including anchor tags in header, footer everything) are changing to green color.

How to restrict this.

I am thinking of using iframe in my email content rendering part.

Kindly give me your valuable suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CSS selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp) such as ID or classes.

If you want to differentiate between your response style and any other style, you would create a class named response `.response` and use that to reference your `a` tags.

The css would look like:

```
.response a {color:green}
```

and the html would look like:

```
<div class="response">
  <!--all the response stuff here-->
  <a href"http://stackoverflow.com">Some link in the response</a>
</div>
```

Comment: No, i cannot use css selectors, because i never know what kind of email content (response) is going to come. Its not under my control

Comment: @Karthikeyan But it should be under your control what the div that the response appears in will be called. If you give a div a class or id, you can reference any of that div's child elements by the div's class or id name.

Comment: @Karthikeyan and if you *need* your style to override any incoming style, you can use the `!important` suffix to make sure your css is the prioritized styling as opposed to any css that may come after it. This will override **everything** else, so don't use it if you don't have to.

Comment: Yeah, i can use important. but if do like that, need to put important for almost html tags.

Answer (score 0):

Let's learn something from roundcube experience. Here we can see how they did it (in shortcut version):

```
<div id="messagecontent"> ... </div>
```

But... roundcube **add unique id to every rule in style**.

The other solutions to avoid style overriding:

- remove `<style>` tags
- put it in `<iframe>` *(as you suggested)*